Why PHP file_put_contents causes NGINX "upstream prematurely closed..."?
I have an Angular webapp running with a PHP backend. Further I'm using SLIM as the webserver and this worked fine for several years. In the SLIM webserver is a simple file cache integrated.
Suddenly I receive upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream as soon as the file cache is activated. I was able to find the line in code that causes the error. It is the point where I call file_put_contents. But I don't understand why? What is going wrong and how can I fix it?
I already tried to find a solution and tried several approaches found to modify my nginx.conf. But nothing worked!
Please does anybody has a solution!
nginx.conf
#nginx
proxy_buffering off;

#fastcgi
fastcgi_buffering off;


# serve any request starting with `/rest` with the following location
location ~ /rest {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /rest/index.php$is_args$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_send_timeout 3600s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
    }
}

# serve all the other requests with the Angular app
location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";


Check write permission on the directory. Also try increasing Buffer Sizes and Timeouts on both php.ini and NGINX configuration

already tried :-/ The permissions exist, buffers are off (for testing) and I already tried timeouts of 3600s.

If you are using SELinux or AppArmor check that they are not blocking file write permission. Also make sure that the target Hard Drive is not really full.

both is checked. It's running on Ubuntu 22.04 in a Plesk environment and it was working in the past. No idea what happened

Extract a [mcve], for a start. Nobody here even knows your setup and PHP config, let alone the code or whether writing the file succeeds or not.

Look for error messages in the PHP error log.
